# where is Android Studio with Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've downloaded Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html but it doesn't install the Android SDK... Did I miss something, or is there another setup somewhere else?

(I see here: [screenshot](https://cdn57.androidauthority.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Android-Studio-Installation-Paths.png) that the setup window should allow the installation of Android SDK, but I don't have that in my setup)

Comment: Watch it what you missed [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this answer elsewhere:

> Apparently, the problem was that Android Studio 3.0 was already installed and uninstalled before this. The SDK got removed, but Android Studio's config didn't.
>
> Removing the config from a previous install (C:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.0 folder) did the trick. When Android Studio started up, it opened a dialog about which parts of the SDK to download, and then proceeded as expected.

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you did not miss anything. With installation of android studio SDK does not install automatically. You need to launch android studio then it will automatically prompt you for sdk installation and then install **SDk** and repositories. And done.

Comment: When I launch Android Studio it asks me for an existing SDK folder: http://62.210.252.209/Download/android_sdk.png

Comment: and the link given (http://d.android.com/sdk) just redirects to the studio download page...

Answer (score 0):

> It will prompt after installing Android Studio

If you are using Windows:

To install Android Studio on Windows, proceed as follows:

**Step1**: Launch the .exe file you downloaded from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

**Step2**: Follow the setup wizard to install Android Studio and any necessary SDK tools.

That's it! The following video shows each step of the recommended setup procedure.

As suggested from official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

Comment: My setup is different as in the video, I don't have the checkbox "Android SDK" in "select components to install" : http://62.210.252.209/Download/android_sdk_setup.png